# bottom navigation view doesnt shows fargment unless double click

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, mdc

i fixed the previous error but now this here. fragment isnt visible if i dont click bottom navigation two times. my code:

activity_main.xml

```
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
    android:id="@+id/FragmentContainerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu" />
```

MainActivity.kt

```
binding.bottomNavigation.setOnItemReselectedListener { item ->
        when(item.itemId) {
            R.id.home -> {
                replaceFragment(HomeFragment())
            }
            R.id.favs -> {
                replaceFragment(FavsFragment())
            }
        }
    }
}

private fun replaceFragment(fragment: Fragment) {
    val fragmentManager = supportFragmentManager
    val fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()

    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.FragmentContainerView, fragment)
    fragmentTransaction.commit()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `setOnItemReselectedListener` you should use `setOnItemSelectedListener` to avoid "double-clicking".

But you still have to add initial fragment to FragmentContainerView. For example, in `onCreate()` you can call your `replaceFragment()` with the fragment that you need to be shown at first.

Comment: FragmentContainerViev does not specify a navigation, therefore it does not appear

Comment: Everything works with BottomNavigation and FragmentContainerView. I tried to replace the setOnItemSelectedListener by the setOnItemReselectedListener in my app with BottomNavigation, and the behavior has become as described by the author

Comment: Oh thanks. But when I launch app first time, just empty screen, I need to select a item to get something. What should I do

Answer (score 1):

First we create navigation.xml (you can create navigation.xml if you click the ResourceManager button on the left, select navigation at the top and click the + sign), then we name it my_nav and click the new destination button on the top and select all the fragments you will use. I suggest you to select your main fragment first

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/my_nav" />
```

or try this

```
binding.bottomNavigation.setItemSelected(R.id.home, true)
```

by the way, some advice for you

```
binding.apply{
//If I do it this way, you don't need to write bindings for your objects every time.
//eg:
  bottomNavigation.setOnItemReselectedListener { item ->        
    }
}
```

Comment: Did the code work for you? If so, please click the tick.